# Show that in general $\inf \sup \ne \sup \inf$ for bilinear functions

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum, bilinear-form

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and let $F(K,L) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
>
> $$ F(x, \lambda) := c^Tx + \lambda^Tb - \lambda Ax \quad ( \ c \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}^m, A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}).$$
>
> Let further
>
> $$M := \inf_{x \in K} \sup_{\lambda \in L} \ F(x, \lambda)$$
> $$N := \sup_{\lambda \in L} \inf_{x \in K} \ F(x, \lambda).$$
>
> Show that in general $M \ne N$.

I can not find an example where that happens however. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $m=n=1$, $K=L=\{0,1\}$, $c=b=1$, $A=-2$.  Then $F(x,\lambda) = x+\lambda -2x\lambda$.

We have:

- $\sup_\lambda F(0,\lambda)=1$
- $\sup_\lambda F(1,\lambda)=1$
- So $\inf_x\sup_\lambda F(x,\lambda)=1$

Whereas:

- $\inf_x F(x,0) = 0$
- $\inf_x F(x,1)=0$
- So $\sup_\lambda \inf_x F(x,\lambda)=0$.